# Stop scrolling after loading more data in GridView Android

Tags: android, gridview, google-play

I am loading some data on first showing the gridview then on scroll i am loading more data into the custom adapter. This is the ok part.

The part i don't understand is how to stop the scroll from moving unless the user scrolls. Silent loading the data in the adapter.

This is my code:

```
int offset = (int) (gridView.getHeight() * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
int index = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
final View first = gridView.getChildAt(0);
if (null != first) {
offset -= first.getTop();
}
gridView.setSelection(index);
gridView.scrollBy(0, offset);
```

I can the that the Google Play app does this with ease, but how i am trying to figure out. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried storing offset before updating adapter with:

```
int offset = gridview.getScrollY();
// update adapter
gridview.setScrollY(offset);
```

Comment: can you stop scrolling up when gridview is tapped?

Comment: You could always override onTouch or onClick by setting onTouchListener or onClickListener, but usually more overrides will make for more issues to solve.